# Upload multiple compressed shapefiles to GeoServer through GeoServer API

Tags: qgis, geoserver, shapefile, node-js

Currently, I am trying to upload a file that compressed the shapefile elements on the local server through GeoServer REST API, but there is a blockage.

Currently, I am using nodejs and making a function to upload several shapefiles through for statement.

It's my code.

```
enter code for (let data of duplicateLayerList) {
    let reader;
    let writer;
    let cmdMainString = `ogr2ogr -f "GEOJSON" "public/images/jsonData/${data}.geojson" -where "Layer='${data}'" ${dxfNameSample1} entities`;

    let cmdResult = exec.execSync(cmdMainString)
    let zipResult = await makeZipFile(data)
    console.log(zipResult)
    var headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/zip",
    };
    let zipFileData = fs.readFileSync("public/images/jsonData/"+data+".zip");
    // let zipFileData = await streamToBuffer(fs.createReadStream('public/images/jsonData/'+data+'.zip'));
    console.log(zipFileData)
    var options = {
      url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/datas/datastores/datas/file.shp",
      //   url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/tiger/datastores/nyc/file.shp",
      method: "PUT",
      headers: headers,
      body: zipFileData,
      auth: {
        user: "admin",
        pass: "geoserver",
      },
      error : (err) => {
        console.log(err)
      }
    };
    let returnBody = await doRequest(options);
```

I use the PUT method for asynchronous communication in the code, I want to put 12 layers in the stores, but only 3 shapefiles are being input.

I want to create it using POST, but when I looked it up on Google, I couldn't implement it because it only showed how to use PUT, so can I know if there is a setting that allows me to use POST in GeoServer API? Or is there a way to upload all 12 files using PUT?

---

> [servlet.PageNotFound] - Request method 'POST' not supported

This is the GeoServer error log that occurred when using the POST method

Comment: Are you sure you have shapefiles? you seem to be zipping GeoJSON

Comment: that's not how REST works, you probably want to zip all your files together and try for a directoy of shapefiles but it will still be a PUT

Comment: Are you saying that I can't send it by post on the code I made?

Comment: the project https://github.com/meggsimum/geoserver-node-client might be useful for many REST based operations. Maybe also as a template for implementing your own